# Image Display (Content) View

Tags: views

Drupal 7

I created an Image Display (Content) View for a different image to display on each page of my site in the second sidebar. When I created the view and uploaded an image to Basic Page...the photo now appears on every page of my site.

How do I modify the view that each page (Basic Page) can have a unique image?

Comment: It sounds like the view is displaying the most recent image.  Why do you need a view?  You could just do this by adding a block or a image_field to the Basic Page content type.

Answer (score 2):

very block has a "visibility setting". Select "Only the listed pages" and enter the pages where you want this block to show.